# How to check if the current user is admin from macOS Xcode using swift?

Tags: c, macos, core-foundation, core-services

I tried using identity services tool but seeing multiple errors

```
CSIdentityRef currentUserIdentity(CFErrorRef *error) {
    CSIdentityQueryRef const query = CSIdentityQueryCreateForCurrentUser(NULL);
    if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(query, 0 /* flags, none needed */, error)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CFArrayRef const users = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(query);
    if (CFArrayGetCount(users) != 1) {
        // TODO: set `*error`
        return NULL;
    }

    return (CSIdentityRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(users, 0);
}

CSIdentityRef adminGroupIdentity(CFErrorRef *error) {
    CSIdentityQueryRef const query = CSIdentityQueryCreateForName(NULL, CFSTR("admin"), kCSIdentityQueryStringEquals, kCSIdentityClassGroup, CSGetDefaultIdentityAuthority());
    if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(query, 0 /* flags, none needed */, error)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CFArrayRef const groups = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(query);
    if (CFArrayGetCount(groups) != 1) {
        // TODO: Set `*error`
        return NULL;
    }

    return (CSIdentityRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groups, 0);
}
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: That's for Swift?  NULL?  Does Swift use it?

Comment: No, this is C using the Core Foundation framework et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is C code which cannot be executed literally in Swift.

The *translation* is

```
func currentUserIdentity() -> CSIdentity? {
    guard let query = CSIdentityQueryCreateForCurrentUser(nil) else { return nil }
    let queryRef = query.takeRetainedValue()
    defer { CSIdentityQueryStop(queryRef) }
    guard CSIdentityQueryExecute(queryRef, 0, nil) else { return nil }
    let users = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(queryRef).takeRetainedValue() as! [CSIdentity]
    return users.first
}

func adminGroupIdentity() -> CSIdentity? {
    let authority = CSGetDefaultIdentityAuthority().takeUnretainedValue()
    guard let query = CSIdentityQueryCreateForName(nil, "admin" as CFString, kCSIdentityQueryStringEquals, kCSIdentityClassGroup, authority) else { return nil }
    let queryRef = query.takeRetainedValue()
    defer { CSIdentityQueryStop(queryRef) }
    guard CSIdentityQueryExecute(queryRef, 0, nil) else { return nil }
    let admins = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(queryRef).takeRetainedValue() as! [CSIdentity]
    return admins.first
}

if let user = currentUserIdentity(),
   let adminGroup = adminGroupIdentity() {
    let memberIsAdmin = CSIdentityIsMemberOfGroup(user, adminGroup)
    let name = CSIdentityGetFullName(user).takeUnretainedValue() as String
    print("current user \(name) is admin:", memberIsAdmin)
} else {
    print("current user cannot be determined")
}
```